# What are the folders in the lib folder in Glassfish for, and how should you use them?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I have just downloaded Hibernate because I want to use it as a persistence provider instead of Eclipselink and you are supposed to put them in the lib folder in your domain in Glassfish. However there are 4 other folders there. What are they for and how to use them?

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using the Hibernate provider instead of the built-in EclipseLink?

Comment: Because I am going to ise Hibernate Search soon:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the [GlassFish documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24930/class-loaders.htm#beadk):

> Optional packages are packages of Java classes and associated native
>   code that application developers can use to extend the functionality
>   of the core platform.
>
> To use the Java optional package mechanism, copy the JAR files into
>   the *domain-dir* `/lib/ext` directory, or use the `asadmin add-library`
>   command with the `--type ext` option, then restart the server.

For a full documentation of the Class Loaders used by GlassFish, see the [chapter on class loaders](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24930/class-loaders.htm#beade).