# Glassfish: exception after downloading client

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, network-programming, ejb, glassfish-3

After developing a Java EE Server and Client with help of Remote API, I tried to run this app from another workstation. Then I encountered a problem. After downloading client through web browser from the address "http://myip:8080/EntAppClient" I receive *"Unable to launch the application"* error. I use Glassfish 3.0.1 (NetBeans cannot install more recent versions). My app was created on a base from that tutorial: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/entappclient.html .

[Update: 15 I 2013]

Ok. So thanks to the [Netbeans 7.1.2 - Unable to add glassfish server 3.1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799825/netbeans-7-1-2-unable-to-add-glassfish-server-3-1-2/13800264#13800264) I managed to run the most recent version of glassfish, and now I have:

**Error:** Unable to load resource: http://myip:8080/___JWSappclient/___system/___dyn/___system_s1as.jnlp

Is the **Launch file** tab important as a part of description of problem?

**Exception** is now:

```
com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Unable to load resource: http://myip:8080/___JWSappclient/___system/___dyn/___system_s1as.jnlp
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine._downloadCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getJreResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload._downloadExtensionsHelper(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload.downloadExtensionsHelper(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload.downloadExtensions(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareLaunchFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareAllResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

And **Wrapped Exception** :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://myip:8080/___JWSappclient/___system/___dyn/___system_s1as.jnlp
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor1.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doGetRequestEX(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine._downloadCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getJreResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload._downloadExtensionsHelper(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload.downloadExtensionsHelper(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload.downloadExtensions(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareLaunchFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareAllResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://myip:8080/___JWSappclient/___system/___dyn/___system_s1as.jnlp
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    ... 19 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your lib to Glassfish i have same problem once :)

Also you could look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056010/what-are-the-folders-in-the-lib-folder-in-glassfish-for-and-how-should-you-use)

Comment: Ok. So it helped me with one of problems.